# Outlook Interop: find mail in sent folder

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I create a `MailItem` from a WPF app and display it to the user:

```
Application _application = new Application();
MailItem mailItem = _outlook.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
mailItem.Display(false);
```

After user has clicked on *Send* the `MailItem` is saved in db (`MailItem` is then associated with a PK):

```
_application.ItemSend += Application_ItemSend;
// ...
private void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    MailItem mailItem = Item as MailItem;
    // Save mailItem in db ...
}
```

After that I need to find the `MailItem` when it's copied to Outlook's sent folder and mark in in db as 'sent':

```
private static void TrackSentFolder(Data.Entity.Person person)
{
    MAPIFolder sentFolder = _nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
    // Find previously created MailItem ...
```

In my research I tried several ways to find MailItem in sent folder:

1. Mark `MailItem` using `UserProperty` before send
2. Mark `MailItem` using `PropertyAccessor` before send
3. Save `MailItem` together with `PR_SEARCH_KEY` in db

I find this rather confusing.

**Is there a recommended way to find a previously created `MailItem` in sent folder?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no recommended way of identifying the item after sending it. It is up to you which way is to choose. Every method described in your post can be used.

Be aware, the `Sent Items` folder can be skipped if the [MailItem.DeleteAfterSubmit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.deleteaftersubmit) property is set. Also the [MailItem.SaveSentMessageFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.savesentmessagefolder) property allows setting a `Folder` object that represents the folder in which a copy of the email message will be saved after being sent.